# Change colors of a single geom_ribbon() depending on variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a `geom_ribbon()` where I make the color of the band conditional on a variable.

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tribble(
  ~year, ~lower, ~upper, ~type,
  2001, 150, 222, "A",
  2002, 53, 64, "A",
  2003, 31, 64, "B",
  2004, 10, 18, "B",
  2005, 30, 49, "B",
  2006, 37, 43, "A",
  2007, 54, 77, "B",
  2008, 58, 89, "A",
  2009, 50, 111, "A",
  2010, 40, 81, "A",
  2011, 49, 63, "A"
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = type))
```

Which creates:

[image]

This creates two separate bands, but I only want to change the colors of *one* combined band.

Comment: What do you mean with changing the colors of one combined band?

Comment: You can use `scale_fill_manual` to set the fill colors however you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in `ggplot` you cannot have more than one color per line, we can expand the data into multiple lines that connect to each other so they appear to be one line. Then we can assign each section a color.

To make sure they appear connected, we have to expand the data so that the start of the next group and the end of the previous group have the same `x` and `y` coordinates, but different groups:

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
df$group <- rleid(df$type)
df_plot <- head(do.call(rbind, by(df, df$group, rbind, NA)), -1)
df_plot[,c("group","type")] <- lapply(df_plot[,c("group","type")], na.locf)
df_plot[] <- lapply(df_plot, na.locf, fromLast = TRUE)

ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, fill = type, group = group))
```

[image]

---

Compare this to the original, uncolored line:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper))
```

[image]

One note - I `lapply` with the `na.locf` so the type doesnt get changed on me. I am aware you can do `na.locf(df_plot)`.