# Is it possible to create a smooth, large geom_line() with varying colors in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was originally going to use a ribbon for this function, but ribbon was giving me an "Aesthetics can not vary within a ribbon" error. I tried a geom_smooth, geom_ribbon, and geom_line, and none of them worked for what I needed. The picture posted below is what I need, except that I would like those square joints between where the line changes colors to be either vertical and flush or round.

I looked at these posts already:

[Shade Fill or Cover Area Density Under Curve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189453/shade-fill-or-color-area-under-density-curve-by-quantile)

[R ggplot Issue When Using Group Interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333816/r-ggplot-issue-when-using-group-interaction-with-geom-ribbon-missing-data)

I've also tried using groups in a couple different ways. I should mention that I'm extremely new to ggplot2 and R in general, so any help or possible avenues would be appreciated. I've been using these resources, which you might find useful for this problem or for your own:

[R For Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/)

[GGPlot2: Elegant Graphics For Data Analysis](https://ggplot2-book.org/index.html)

[GGPlot2 Documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html)

[R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/)

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)

pdf("ggplot_learning.pdf")

data <- data.frame(
  xvals = c(0:5),
  yvals = c(4, 5, 4.5, 5.5, 5, 6),
  lower = c(3.9, 4.9, 4.4, 5.4, 4.9, 5.9),
  upper = c(4.1, 5.1, 4.6, 5.6, 5.1, 6.1)
)


plot <- ggplot(data, aes(xvals, yvals, ymax = 8, xmax = 8)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = yvals, alpha = .3), lwd = 10) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = yvals)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")

print(plot)
```

What I have so far:

[image: Graph With Rough Idea of What I Need]

Comment: So you want to fill the area under the curve with five different colors, right?

Comment: Originally, it would've been a ribbon that surrounded the line. The ymin and ymax of the ribbon are going to be std deviations (I'm actually not sure if std deviations is the right word, perhaps variation?), so it should be centered around the line. The colors should vary based on the y-values, so if there were more than 5 y-values there would be more than 5 colors. Here though it would be 5 :-)

Comment: did you look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217794/change-colors-of-a-single-geom-ribbon-depending-on-variable

Comment: No, I didn't find that in my searches, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure but maybe this:

```
data2 <- rbind(data, data[-1,]) 
data2 <- data2[order(data2$xvals),]
data2$n <- factor(head(rep(1:6, each=2),-1))

ggplot(data2, aes(xvals, yvals,color=n, fill=n, group=n)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Since you need groups for the `geom_ribbon` function, you need to specify each section. Thus, from 0 to 1, from 1 to 2 ...
Therfore, I `rbind` the data twice, sort according to `x` and add a grouping factor `n`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your code? I'm still trying to learn the syntax :)

Comment: After looking at it more... You're creating a new data frame using rbind which excludes the last row. I'm not sure what the second line does. The third line is setting a new variable n to be equal to the levels 1,2,3,4,5,6 . Can you explain why you used rep and head inside factor, and also what line 2 is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that looks *a little* better with `geom_path`, but it seems to ignore the `linejoin =` argument when the colors change:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = xvals, y = yvals)) + 
  geom_path(aes(color = yvals, alpha = .3), lwd = 10,
            lineend="round",linejoin="miter") + 
  geom_line(aes(color = yvals)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: That's weird, I tried linejoin and lineend and I couldn't get it to show up like this. Definitely a step forward. I'll take another crack at it, see if I can get it to show up like this. Thanks!

Comment: I was using a line and not a path!