# Logarithmic Scale is Not Working on Y-Axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

[image]

[image]

```r
plot <- ggplot(Intel, aes(x = Date, y = log(Adj.Close))) +
  geom_line(aes(size = Volume)) + 
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", labels = date_format("%Y"))
```

My graph should look like the first image, but looks like the second. I have no clue why the y-axis will not adjust. I do not understand log scales, but need to use log 10 here. Can someone tell me why the graphs look so different and how to fix?

Comment: What in particular do you not like about/is wrong with the third image (presumably done with `y = Adj.Close`)? Is it the width of the line?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer less width or another way to display - but don't know if that's possible. It's hard to decipher the volume amounts from each other because thickness is hard to read

Comment: well, "another way to display" is a different question (you could use changing colour, but it's not directly possible to use `geom_line()` with changing colours within a single line - I'm sure there are SO questions about this [see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217794/change-colors-of-a-single-geom-ribbon-depending-on-variable)]]). See `?scale_size` for options to change the range of sizes used, especially the `range` argument. **Without a reproducible example it's hard to help you much more.**

Answer (score 1):

To be sure we would probably need a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but my strong suspicion is that you should use `y = Adj.Close` rather than `y = log(Adj.Close)` in your `mapping` specification (the second argument of `ggplot`, the stuff with `aes()`). The `scale_y_log10()` statement is supposed to take care of everything, so I think you're effectively doubly logging your data.

Comment: I've done as you said and it does fix the image to at least make sense. However, the data still doesn't look like how it's supposed to. I have updated the image if that helps. But, I don't know why the first chart still looks so different

Comment: can we have a [mcve]?